# TreeView nodes from other form

Tags: c#, treeview

I have a TreeView with dinamically created nodes.

I want to reach the nodes from other form, when i close the other form.

But it does not work.

Sample:

form1

```
//show the other form (form2)
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (Form1 form1 = new Form1())
        {
            using (Form2 form2 = new Form2(form1))
            {
                form2.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
                form2.ShowDialog();
            }
        }
    }

    //call this method from other form (form2) when close
    internal void example()
    {
        MessageBox.Show(treeView1.Nodes.Count.ToString());
    }

    //create the nodes
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TreeNode node = new TreeNode("aaaa");
        treeView1.Nodes.Add(node);
        node = new TreeNode("bbbb");
        treeView1.Nodes.Add(node);
        node = new TreeNode("cccc");
        treeView1.Nodes.Add(node);
    }
```

form2

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    Form1 form1;

    public Form2(Form1 form1)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.form1 = form1;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
        form1.example();
    }
}
```

MessageBox.Show(treeView1.Nodes.Count.ToString());

result: 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is in this line:

```
using (Form1 form1 = new Form1())
```

you're sending new instance of `Form1` to your `Form2`. You should send current instance of `Form1`, like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (Form2 form2 = new Form2(this))
    {
        form2.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
        form2.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ehh, what a fundamental mistake...Thanks for your blazingly fast answer!

Answer (score 1):

You construct Form1 twice. Once to show a form with a button. When the button is pressed you create another instance of Form1. This second instance is given to Form2. But... the Load event of the second instance is never called, meaning its tree is never filled. The Load event is only called when the form is displayed, and this instance is never displayed.

I suggest you follow the answer of Nino.

Or... if you insist to have multiple instances of Form1, move the code which fills the tree, inside the constructor of Form1, not in the Load-eventhandler.

Comment: upvote for an explanation that i was too lazy to write :)

Comment: Thank you!

@Nino Never mind, i understood what the problem was.